# Understanding optional global variables in swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm working through a book on Swift and I understand the idea of scope in functions so what I'd like to understand next is why we set global variables using optional types in classes.  Honestly it looks like we don't set these variables per say but just let the class know that there will be a variable of a specific type somewhere throughout the code base: `var sut: ItemManager!`.

From what I understand the variable sut is an unwrapped optional of the type ItemManger which definitely has a valid value and not nil.  The reason we've set it with an exclamation mark or question mark is because there isn't an initializer within this class.  What isn't clear is since this class doesn't have an initializer, what factors come into play when deciding weather to set this global variable to an optional using a questions mark or implicitly unwrapped with an exclamation mark?

```
import XCTest
    @testable import ToDo

    class ItemManagerTests: XCTestCase {

        var sut: ItemManager!

        override func setUp() {
            super.setUp()
            // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

            sut = ItemManager.init()
        }

        override func tearDown() {
            // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
            super.tearDown()
        }


        func test_ToDoCount_InitiallySetAtZero(){

            let sut = ItemManager.init()

            XCTAssertEqual(sut.toDoCount, 0)
        }

        func test_DoneCount_InitiallySetAtZero(){

            let sut = ItemManager.init()

            XCTAssertEqual(sut.doneCount, 0)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason we've set it with an exclamation mark or question mark is
>   because there isn't an initializer within this class

Because when every instance of a class is initialized, it has to allocate memory for its properties/instance var. So with `var sut: ItemManager!`, the value of `sut` is `nil` when `init`. Without `!`, `?` the compiler can't allocate, init, so you have to init manually in an initializer. That is what compiler told you.

For using `!` or `?`.

- `!` is used when the property/var always has value after the first assigning. And after the first time it's assigned, it can't be nil later
- `?` is used when the pro/var can have value or not

Comment: Neither claim in the first item in your list is correct. It's perfectly fine for IUO to not have a value – just make sure you don't access them without one.

Answer (score 3):

`sut` is not a global variable.

`sut` is an *instance variable* of the `ItemManagerTests`. Every time a new instance, i.e. an object, of a `ItemManagerTests` is instantiated, memory is allocated for `sut`.

It's of type `ItemManager!`. This is an implicitly unwrapped optional. It's similar to `ItemManager?` (a.k.a. Optional), with the distinction that it is implicitly forcefully unwrapped everywhere it's used directly, as if the force unwrap operator (`!`) was used.

Its value is initialized to `nil`, but is set to a new `ItemManager` object when `setUp` is called by Xcode's testing framework.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `sut` is not a global.  A global variable in Swift is declared outside any enclosing scope (So, before the `class` statement).  `sut` is an instance property; each instance of your `ItemManagerTests` class will have a `sut` property.

In Swift, all non-optional properties must be initialised by the time the initialiser has completed.  In some cases this can be achieved by code inside the initialiser and in other cases by assigning a default value.

In some cases, s you cannot assign or don't want to assign a default value and you can't (or don't want to) override the initialiser.

If you used a normal optional then the compiler would be satisfied that the property wasn't initialised by default or in the initialiser, but each time you referred to the property you would have to unwrap it (e.g. `sut?.donecount`).

Since  your test case is assigning a value to `sut` in `setup`, you know that it will have a value and you could use a force unwrap (e.g. `sut!.donecount`), or, take it one step further and use an implicitly unwrapped optional.  This allows you to refer to the property without any unwrapping, but it is still an optional and will still cause a crash if it is `nil`.

Note that your current code isn't even using the property, since you are allocating a local variable in your test cases.  You can use:

```
class ItemManagerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: ItemManager!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        sut = ItemManager.init()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func test_ToDoCount_InitiallySetAtZero() {

        XCTAssertEqual(sut.toDoCount, 0)
    }

    func test_DoneCount_InitiallySetAtZero() {

        XCTAssertEqual(sut.doneCount, 0)
    }
}
```