# Basic Firebase Database Problems (Xcode + Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to using firebase, in my FirstViewController, when I import FirebaseDatabase it Xcode imediatly shows an error on line 13 (class def for firstviewcontroller). `/Users/admin/Documents/shneckleclicker2/shneckleclicker2/FirstViewController.swift:13:7: Class 'FirstViewController' has no initializers`

However when I remove the line `var ref: FIRDatabaseReference` the error disapears.

Code in FirstViewController:

```
import UIKit
import NotificationCenter
import FirebaseDatabase

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

   var ref: FIRDatabaseReference
```

Comment: Read answer here-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358714/understanding-optional-global-variables-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let ref: FIRDatabaseReference! Requires force unwrapping

Answer (score 0):

Xcode show error because "ref" is not initialised. You can replace

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference
```

with

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference? = nil
```

The "?" shows that its an optional so you need to unwrap it before using it like this:

```
let reference = ref! // Assigning Value
setReference(ref!) // Calling a Method
```